# Merge the two object based on keyValue using Lodash

Tags: javascript, lodash

I want to merge two objects using Lodash based on `key:value`, here I need to compare the `itemId` and `id`, and if the two values are equal I want to add the `price` and `itemId` to the list.  Below I show a small example as well as the expected output:

```
item:{
    itemStatus:[
        { itemId:1, status: true, price:200 },
        { itemId:2, status: true, price:500 }
   ],
    menuItem:[
        { id:1, name:'buddy', status: true},
        { id:2, name:'buddy22', status: true},
        { id:3, name:'buddy44', status: true}
    ]
}
```

My result should be like this:

```
{ id:1, itemId:1, name:'buddy', status: true, price:200},
{ id:2, itemId:2, name:'buddy22', status: true, price:500},
{ id:3, itemId:3, name:'buddy44', status: true}
```

I tried using this code:

```
var arrResult = _.map(menuItem, function(obj) {
    return _.assign(obj, _.find(itemStatus, {
        itemId: obj.id
    }));
});
```

but `itemId` is replacing the `id`.  Can someone rewrite the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`_.keyBy()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#keyBy) on both arrays, to convert them to an object with the ids/itemIds as keys. Then use [`_.merge()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#merge) to combine both objects, and convert back to an array using [`_.values()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#values):

```js
var itemStatus = [{"itemId":1,"status":true,"price":200},{"itemId":2,"status":true,"price":500}];

var menuItems = [{"id":1,"name":"buddy","status":true},{"id":2,"name":"buddy22","status":true},{"id":3,"name":"buddy44","status":true}];

var result = _.values(_.merge( // merge the objects and get the array
  _.keyBy(menuItems, 'id'), // create an on object of menuItems by id
  _.keyBy(itemStatus, 'itemId') // create an object of itemStatus by id
));

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

This should solve your problem:

```
var arrResult = _.map(item.menuItem, function(obj) {
    return _.assign({}, obj, _.find(item.itemStatus, {
        itemId: obj.id
    }));
});
```